# Can the apply function in pandas groupby return more than one dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I want to do two slightly different operations in an `apply` functions for `groupby` as given in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2,2], 'y':['aaa','bbb','ccc']})
print(df)

def func1(x):
    stackrow = pd.concat([x, x], axis=0, keys=['a', 'b'], names=['w', 'z'])
    return(stackrow)

df2 = df.groupby('x').apply(func1)
print("***********************\ndf2:")
print(df2)

def func2(x):
    stackcol = pd.concat([x, x], axis=1, keys=['c', 'd'], names=['w', 'z'])
    return(stackcol)

df3 = df.groupby('x').apply(func2)
print("***********************\ndf3:")
print(df3)
```

However, as I mentioned `func1` and `func2` in my real example have a significantly overlapping functionality and I do not want to re-excute the code for that common functionality. I was wondering if the following code wold work.

```
def func(x):
    stackrow = pd.concat([x, x], axis=0, keys=['a', 'b'], names=['z'])
    stackcol = pd.concat([x, x], axis=1, keys=['c', 'b'], names=['w'])
    return(stackrow, stackcol)

df4, df5 = df.groupby('x').apply(func)

print("***********************\ndf4:")
print(df4)
print("***********************\ndf5:")
print(df5)
```

But it does not seem to work as `df2!=df4` and `df3!=df5`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nested DataFrame seems to work.

```
def func(df):
    # reseting index to avoid some error in pd.concat later not sure why
    x = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    stackrow = pd.concat([x, x], axis=0, keys=['a', 'b'], names=['w', 'z'])
    stackcol = pd.concat([x, x], axis=1, keys=['c', 'd'], names=['p', 'q'])
    newdf = pd.DataFrame([[stackrow, stackcol]])
    return(newdf)

tmp = df.groupby('x').apply(func)

df4 = pd.concat(tmp[0].tolist())
df5 = pd.concat(tmp[1].tolist())
print("***********************\ndf4:\n", df4)
print("***********************\ndf5:\n", df5)
```

Or, better to keep the grouping variables in the index:

```
df44 = tmp[[0]].groupby('x').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0,0])
df55 = tmp[[1]].groupby('x').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0,0])
print("***********************\ndf44:\n", df44)
print("***********************\ndf55:\n", df55)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the groups and call the function directly

```
gb = df.groupby('x') 
for group_name, group_lables in gb.groups.items(): 
    df4, df5 = func(gb.get_group(group_name)) 
    # do something more with the dfs?
```

Comment: I like the idea. However, I was wondering if sometime like nested dataframe and explode can be used here.